# Keras: Feature maps graph disconnected with reconstructed model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, model

This is a strange behaviour and I cant figure out what is happening. I am trying to extract the feature maps of a specific layer. For that purpose, I need to flatten a nested model. So I save all layers in an array and create a new Sequential model.

I will show an example with a simple model:

```
import tensorflow as tf

model1=tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8,(3,3),activation ='relu', input_shape=(150,150,3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16,(3,3),activation ='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation ='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024,activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512,activation='relu'),
    
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3,activation='softmax')    
 ])


all_layers = model1.layers

model2 = tf.keras.models.Sequential(all_layers)


feature_maps_model1 = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model1.inputs, outputs=model.layers[1].output)

feature_maps_model2 = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model2.inputs, outputs=model2.layers[1].output)
```

So I expect model1 and model2 (reconstructed model) to be exactly the same. The summary() also suggests that. However, that is not the case. When I compute "feature_maps_model1", everything goes fine. But when I compute "feature_maps_model2 ", I get this annoying error:

`Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 150, 150, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='conv2d_input'), name='conv2d_input', description="created by layer 'conv2d_input'") at layer "conv2d". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []`

What is happening here? Why the reconstructed model is giving this error when I try to extract the feature maps? The models should be equivalent.

Comment: Btw, this is the only workaround that I found, but I shouldn't need to go this far.

    `model2 = keras.models.Sequential()
    for i, layer in enumerate(all_layers[1:]):
        layer_type = layer.__class__.__name__
        new_layer = getattr(keras.layers, layer_type)
        args = dict(layer.get_config().items())
        if i == 0:
            args['input_shape'] = layers_flat[0].input.shape[1:]
        new_layer = new_layer(**args)
        model2.add(new_layer)`